# Facebook popup not closing

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api

I have used facebook graph api v2.0 for my .net application

**I inserted following javascript code:**

```
(function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&xfbml=1&appId=" + AppId;
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

**For fb login I used following code:**

```
FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                    //console.log(response); // dump complete info
                    access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
                    user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

                    myMethod();

                } else {
                    //user hit cancel button
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                    return false;
                }
            }, {
                scope: 'publish_stream,email'
            });


function myMethod()
{
FB.api('/me', function (response) {

                    uid = response.id;
                    username = response.username;
                    email = response.email;
                    gender = response.gender;
                    fullname = response.name;
                    firstname = response.first_name;
                    lastname = response.last_name;
                    link = response.link;
//then i perform other operations
                });
}
```

This code does bring out fb popup for login but the problem is many times the popup doesn't close 
and i don't get any response from api.
this thing becomes worse in IE9, I have written meta tag for it but still no use.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9">
```

Does anyone have any solution for it. it's too frustrating, I tried many things but doesn't work.

Comment: why does everyone keep using publish_stream? that permission is deprecated since a very long time...also, the unsername is not included in the response of /me anymore.

Comment: so should i remove the scope or simply publish_Stream?

Comment: remove publish_stream, you are not posting anything anyway in your code. and even if you post something later, you should request publish_actions (the correct permission) right before you actually post something, not at the beginning. read and write permission should not be requested at the same time.

Comment: I changed it, but still no change in output.
It did login successfully once but after hitting ctrl+f5 for 2-3 times.

Comment: a test link would be good

Comment: http://arabsat.whatsonindia.com/Home

on right side u'll see "Connect with facebook" button.

Comment: i see the issue now. never seen that before, to be honest. i´d just file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/